# How to upgrade from Magento 1.7.0 to Magento 1.7.2?

Tags: magento

I have to upgrade a Magento project that is in Magento 1.7.0 to 1.7.2. How can I upgrade and keep all my data?

Comment: It should be the same as any other upgrade: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/standard-procedure-to-upgrade-magento-to-the-newest-version/

Comment: This method works for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade Magento to 1.7.2 using MagentoConnect Manager.
The standard procedure of Magento upgrade is the following:

Backup your files

```
tar -cvvzf your_site_directory.tar.gz your_site_directory/ 2>error.log
```

Backup your database

```
mysqldump -u THIS_IS_YOUR_USERNAME_FOR_DB -h localhost 
    -pTHIS_IS_YOUR_USERNAME_FOR_DB my_database_name | 
    gzip -9 > my_database_name.sql.gz
```

Copy those files to the new location

Import database into new created one:

a) Extract my_database_name.sql.gz
b) `mysql –verbose –user=THIS_IS_YOUR_USERNAME –password=THIS_IS_YOUR_PASSWORD newly_created_db < my_database_name.sql`

Extract the files `tar -xvvzf your_site_directory.tar.gz`

Edit db table core_config_data and set new secure/unsecure URLs of your site

Disable cache from admin.

Delete cache and session directories  located here:

```
/var/cache
/var/session
rm /your_path_to/var/session -R
rm /your_path_to/var/cache -R
```

Execute “clean” bash script located in /downloader/pearlib directory
a) Run `chmod +x clean`  to be able to execute this script
b) ./clean to execute script

Go to Magento connect manager from your Magento admin

Paste this extension to upgrade Magento: `magento-core/Mage_All_Latest`

For more information you can go to: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento#magento_upgrade_guide_for_1.3.x_1.4.x_1.5.x_1.6.x_and_1.7.x